# Jplayer not functionning under WP Twentytwelve / Firefox

Tags: wordpress, firefox, wordpress-theming, html5-audio, jplayer

I am currently working on a Wordpress site. I have put a Jplayer audio player to play mp3s.

I have 2 themes, inheriting from twentyeleven and twentytwelve. The site is currently running with a theme that inherits from twentyeleven, all for the best. Everything works in FF, Chrome and IE (especially audio player).

I am working to build a child theme from twentytwelve. With the same JS includes, the Jplayer doesn't play in FF (18), but works well with Chrome... Especially, the playlist doesn't load (whereas it should).

Strange isn't it ?

Comment: the problem may be here is FF doesnot support mp3 in jplayer.have similar problem in my last project so for chrome you need to have ogg format audio.

Comment: Yes, BUT it worked like a charm in FF in the twentyeleven-inherited theme...

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the solution.

Actually JQuery was loaded twice, in the MailPress subscription form. If someone ever has this kind of issue it might be caused by that double-loading.

See also http://www.jplayer.org/support/ for other kinds of issues.